# place 'axis' at specific coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Is there any way to put `axis` environment at specific coordinates? For example if I want the function plot to be a secondary part of a big tikzpicture.

This is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (coord) at (1,2);
\begin{axis}[anchor=(coord)]
\draw [blue,fill] (Point) circle (2pt) node [right] {(1,2)}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: This perfectly solves my problem! Thank you!

Comment: @Jake Sorry, didn't see your comment before I posted. If you want to write an answer yourself I can always delete mine.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: No problem at all! @ skobls: In addition to accepting the answer, please also upvote it by clicking the upward pointing triangle next to the answer.

Comment: @Jake: now I think he is allowed to :)

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino: Oops, I wasn't aware that there was a rep requirement for voting. Sorry for needlessly rushing things!

Comment: @skobls: Please add a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3343/) next time - like I did.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can specify `at={<coordinate>}` and the `anchor` in the `axis` options. In the following example the `north east` corner of the `axis` is placed in `(10cm,5cm)`. I had to use units for the coordinate, unitless numbers didn't work.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (10,5);

\begin{axis}[
  at={(10cm,5cm)},
  anchor={north east},
  width=5cm,
  height=4cm]
\addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]